# MAX operations in Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: java, database, performance, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to using NoSQL databases. I have a table in DynamoDB with more than 100k items in it. Also, this table gets refreshed frequently. On this table, I want to be able to do something similar to this in the relation database world:

```
Select * 
from tableName 
where attributeName = (Select MAX(attributeName) from tableName);
```

Is there any inexpensive way of doing this without having to fetch all the rows into my Java code? Any inputs/pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cheap way to do this without adding space or complexity.

The expensive way would be to scan the entire table, retrieving only the key attributes and the `attributeName` attribute, compute the max, and then get all of the (complete) items  that you found with that max.

If you have a compound key (hash and range) and few hash keys relative total items in the table, [Local secondary indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.Using) would help, and  cost only a little little space.  You could have an index on the `attributeName` attribute, and then query against each hash key using that index, and the "isScanIndexForward:false" and "limit:1" to get the "max" from that hashKey.  Then you compute the max of all results (1 result from each hashkey), and you know the value to retrieve.  You can retrieve them all in much the same way, with backwards scans and an 'EQ' condition on the `attributeName`.

If you are willing to add complexity, you can store this information in an additional table.  Something like `tableName.extraInfo`, which has an item like this: `{hashKey: "maxOfAttributeName", "value":5}`.  Then when you `put` or `update` the main table you update this field as well, and voila, you have your value.  Beware the transactional complexity that comes with this approach if your data is changing rapidly.

Comment: Note that this answer may no longer be correct.  DynamoDB has since released local secondary indexes.